# run android project on mobile htc hd2

Tags: android, mobile, dimensions

I have a project create with the following dimensions: wsvga(tablet), 7", 1024 x 600.
is there a way to run this project on my mobile, htc h2d without altering the dimensions.
the android version on my mobile is android jelly-bean 4.1

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have created an avd of wsvga resolution not the project

You can always run project on any resolution, but the ui may not show up correctly, if it is not optimized.